# VIsual Studio: Where to configure the Angular publish process?

Tags: angular, visual-studio

I have successfully upgraded my Angular project, which is part of a C# client/server solution, to Angular 14. However. Angular 14 does not build with

```
ng build --prod
```

instead it now uses

```
ng build --configuration production
```

However, I have no clue where to configure this in Visual studio? My publish process fails with this error message:

```
> ng build "--prod"
EXEC(0,0): Error : Unknown argument: prod
```

Now I wonder where I can configure VS so that it will use the new parameter when publishing?   I always thought that would be in the .pubxml PublishProfiles, but I can't find any reference there... Any suggestions?

Comment: Look for that in the *.csproj* file for your web application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to R. Richards comment above I was able to resolve the issue.

This is what is close to the end of my .csproj project file:

```
 [...]
 <Target Name="PublishRunWebpack" AfterTargets="ComputeFilesToPublish">
    <!-- As part of publishing, ensure the JS resources are freshly built in production mode -->
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm install" />
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm run build -- --prod" />
 [...]
```

I changed the --prod parameter like this:

```
 [...]
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm run build -- --configuration production" />
 [...]
```

And voilà it worked. Thanks again, credit goes to R. Richards.

(Running into another issue now as I am using ng-bootstrap in my project which does not seem to support Angular 14 yet, but that is a different story.)